# Using NavLink or Link instead of href in ReactJs

Tags: reactjs, hyperlink, react-router, href

I am trying to use NavLink or Link inside  Dropdown component from "react-bootstrap" library for routing from Header Menu of my website,

Standard Procedure on https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/dropdowns/

says use href

`<Dropdown.Item href="#/action-3">Something else</Dropdown.Item>`

if i use href instead(of Link or NavLink) it works fine but whole page(including header and footer) is refreshed when the link is clicked, I dnt want to refresh the whole page, only the required part (body area) must be refreshed

my code is as follows

```
            <DropdownButton id="IdAbout" className="DropDownStyle" title="About" variant="none">
              <Dropdown.Item className="LinksStyle">
                <NavLink to="/">The Organisation</NavLink>
              </Dropdown.Item>
              <Dropdown.Item className="LinksStyle">
                <NavLink to="/">Our Message</NavLink>
              </Dropdown.Item>
            </DropdownButton>
```

and i get this warning in console.

Warning: validateDOMNesting(...):  cannot appear as a descendant of .

Is there any way to use link instead of href. 
[This is error appears](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XE2pV.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to try this

```
npm install react-router-bootstrap --save
```